# How To Prevent "Grandpa Voter Error" And Randomly Deleted Keystore

Tags: grandpa

We have been experimenting with lots of different configurations to avoid this error, with no luck. Eventually, this error takes the entire network down. **The most interesting part is that the keystores are found deleted.** Has anyone solved this?

**What We Have Tried And What We Know:**

- various flags do not correct the problem: --unsafe-pruning, --pruning archive, --validator (only)
- We are running the substrate kitchen sink node 09.26 in all instances
- We have double checked that the Granpa keys are the correct type (ed25519)
- We have double checked that the keys are correct and that the passwords are entered correctly when starting up.
- This problem seems to occur anywhere from 1600 to 183,257 blocks in (not predictable)
- **Consistently, when the error occurs, you will find the keystore suddenly EMPTY** (if the keystore is being emptied, that would certainly cause the error BUT why would the keystore be deleted?). We cannot tell if the keystore was deleted before or after the grandpa voter error.

**Log Sample:**

2022-10-07 20:04:53 GRANDPA voter error: could not sign outgoing message: Failed to sign GRANDPA vote for round 1669 targetting 0xfc773739b96844d15df0146e218a608b51bd02b0e525a20a8c6b6520074e3ad7
2022-10-07 20:04:53 Essential task `grandpa-voter` failed. Shutting down service.
Error: Service(Other("Essential task failed."))

**Has anyone else had this problem? What are we missing?**

Comment: What kind of node are you running? Is this your custom parachain or standalone chain? If so, could you maybe share a link to the code?

Comment: Substrate is not deleting anything from the keystore. I would highly recommend to check your hard drive or your configuration.

Comment: We are using code from this repo, pulled in August 2022, states it is version 9.26. Standalone chain. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate

Comment: We will be retrying this week with the latest build from that repo to see if it helps. Configuration has been checked a few times but we will check it again.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but the error seems to suggest the keystone is deleted *before* the error, which causes the failure to sign, which causes the node to shut down.

Comment: We wondered that same thing. Further experiments showed that the keystore is there all the way up to the GP Voter Error, but we can't tell exactly which happened first. We noticed that the base path for the keystore (and everything else for the node) is in a tmp folder (according to the standard methods in the instructions). Could it be that this tmp folder is deleted if the node shuts down? That would account for the missing files after the GP Voter Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was mentioned in the validator channel.

The issue was that the node was started with the `--tmp` or `--dev` flag which places all of the node generated files like the keystore into a temporary directory which is cleaned up when the node is shut down.

The answer is to provide a `--base-path` argument, which will place all of those files into a specified path, and that folder wont be cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you Shawn!! We will test this and report back!

Comment: New experiment today shows that if we have a running chain, with a permanent base path, and we delete the session keys out of the keystore folder for Node A, that node will shut down immediately with exactly the same error we have been experiencing. This suggests that having your chain running in a tmp base path risks that Node A's entire existence will be deleted at some point (dependent on the operating system and when they were last accessed, making it seem random). When the session keys are deleted, you get this error. A permanent base path should definitely solve it. Thank you, Shawn!